# Backbone Sinon Fake Server - test server 404 (500) error response

Tags: javascript, server, http-status-code-404, sinon

There are millions of examples and blogs how to create a sinon fakeServer response to 200 OK ajax request, but I can't find any example how to test server error properly.

I have a Backbone Model with "check" function which looks like this:

```js
check: function(callback){
            this.fetch({
                success: function(model, response){
                    if(response.authenticated){
                        if('success' in callback) callback.success(model, response);
                    } else {
                        if('error' in callback) callback.error(model, response);
                    }
                },
                error: function(model, response){
                    if('error' in callback) callback.error(model, response.responseJSON[0]);
                }
            });
        }
```

Than I'm testing this function with Sinon - here it goes:

```js
it("should call callback error on server error", function(done){
                var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
                this.callback = {
                    success:  sinon.spy(),
                    error: sinon.spy()
                };

                this.server.respondWith("GET", "/api/session", [
                    404,
                    { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    '[{"test":"error"}]'
                ]);

                this.model.once('error', function(){
                    expect(this.callback.error.callCount).to.equal(1);
                    expect(this.callback.error.called).to.be.ok;

                    done();
                }, this);

                this.model.check(this.callback);

                //why clock has to be set here at min 10ms?
                clock.tick(10);
            });
```

The test doesn't behave properly until I add clock.tick with at least 10ms value.
The callback.error is handled properly even without clock.tick, but the test is not working then.

Can someone please explain it to me what is going on here ? Am I mixing some concepts ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the test pass if you _do not_ `useFakeTimers` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601587)?

Comment: Wow, actually it's working without fake timers! Thanks